Why do rainscreens require pressure equalization, but masonry cavity walls don't?
I'm not sure if this is right forum to post this, but if any engineer worked on rainscreens and/or masonry cavity walls and could tell me why some rainscreen systems are designed with pressure equalization, but cavity walls AFAIK never need any pressure equalization, I'd be grateful.

lecture from Siderise corroborated by NHBC guidance showed me that pressure equalisation is directly dependent on extent of "leakage" of the external layer of facade. "Open joints" in rainscreens for example are required to have pressure equalisation as their cavities are more exposed. This paper points out that the major driver is wind.
From  all that I inferred that cavity walls with external masonry must be on average sufficiently weathertight not to warrant pressure equalisation in most circumstances.

I don't have sources to quote with me now, but I remember other authors suggesting compartmentalization of facades, the reasoning being that wind can get uneven across facades causing areas within a few meters to differ in pressure and so compartmentalization breaks the facade to match these "area differentials". By the way, I'm new here and didn't expect to meet anyone else interested in these topics. If you are aware of other forums, please let me know.

Yes, I kept coming across this when researching this topic that a major issue was pressure difference between outer layer (rainscreen) and inner layer (SFS/blockwork) pushing water inside the building, particularly at the openings (windows, services, etc.).
